# How to make sense of the micrometer metrics using SpringBoot 2, InfluxDB and Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, metrics, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to configure a SpringBoot application to export metrics to InfluxDB to visualise them using a Grafana dashboard. I'm using [this](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/4701) dashboard as an example which uses Prometheus as a backend.
For some metrics I have no problem figuring out how to create graphs for them but for some others I don't know how to create the graphs or even if it's possible at all. So I enumerate the things I'm not really sure about in the following points:

- Is there any documentation where a value unit is described? The application I'm using as an example doesn't have any load on it so sometimes I don't know whether the value is a bit, a byte, a second, a millisecond, a count, etc.
- Some measurements contain the tag 'metric_type = histogram' with fields 'count', 'sum', 'mean' and 'upper'. Again, here I don't know what the value units are, what upper means or how I'm suppose to plot them. Examples of this are 'http_server_requests' or 'jvm_gc_pause'.
- From what I see in the Grafana dashboard example, it seems I should use these measurements of type histogram to create both a graph with counts and graphs with duration. For example I see I should be able to create a graph with the number of requests and another one with their duration. Or for the garbage collector, I should be able to provide a graph for the number of minor and major GCs and another for their duration.

As an example of measures I get inserted into InfluxDB:

```
time                 count exception mean     method metric_type outcome status sum      upper    uri
1625579637946000000  1     None      0.892144 GET    histogram   SUCCESS 200    0.892144 0.892144 /actuator/health
```

or

```
time                action          cause                 count   mean  metric_type  sum upper
1625581132316000000 end of minor    GC Allocation Failure     1      2  histogram    2   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree the documentation for micrometer is not great. I've had to dig through the code to find answers...

Regarding your questions about **jvm_gc_pause**, it is a [Timer](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_timers) and the implementation is `AbstractTimer` which is a class that wraps a `Histogram` among other components.  This particular metric is registered by the `JvmGcMetrics` class. The various measurements that are published to InfluxDB are determined by the `InfluxMeterRegistry.writeTimer(Timer timer)` method:

- sum: `timer.totalTime(getBaseTimeUnit()) // The total time of recorded events`
- count: `timer.count() // The number of times stop has been called on the timer`
- mean: `timer.mean(getBaseTimeUnit()) // totalTime()/count()`
- upper: `timer.max(getBaseTimeUnit()) // The max time of a single event`

The base time unit is milliseconds.

Similarly, **http_server_requests** appears to be a `Timer` as well.

I believe you are correct that the sensible thing is to chart on two separate Grafana panels: one panel for GC pause seconds using `sum` (or `mean` or `upper`), and one panel for GC events using `count`.